# ZipOutputStream doesn't write file contents

Tags: java, zip, stream

I need to zip data that is coming from one stream and put zipped data to another. Here is the code that operates with files (`MyOutputStream` is a simple FileOutputStream wrapper used for debug purposes). This code works fine.

```
        ZipOutputStream jos = new ZipOutputStream( new MyOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName)));
        jos.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
        jos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test.txt"));
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
             jos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        jos.closeEntry();
        jos.close();
```

In my real application I have to deal with more complex streams. In fact, streams are used for CORBA interop. However, data is successfully read. But when I try to do `jos.write(buffer, 0, len);` no data is written to the output stream that is underlying ZipOutputStream. However, zip file headers, entries comments and central directory are written successfully so I get absolutely valid zip with only one exception that files are empty.

Maybe anyone had seen this behavior before? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is my real code as it may be useful:

```
String fileName = fullSourcePath.substring(fullSourcePath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1, fullSourcePath.length());
WrapperOutputStream out = new WrapperOutputStream(newexchangeStream64);
ZipOutputStream jos = new ZipOutputStream(out);
jos.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);

jos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
jos.setComment("Comment");
IDLDataHolder data = new IDLDataHolder();
LongHolder dataAmount = new LongHolder();
LongHolder written = new LongHolder();

while (true) {
    exchangeStream64.Read(data, READ_AMOUNT, dataAmount);
    if (0 == dataAmount.value) {
        break;
    }

    jos.write(data.value, (int)dataAmount.value, (int)written.value);
}
jos.closeEntry();
jos.close();
```

Comment: Could you post that particular part from your aplication? Or is it too big?

Comment: I don't know `IDLDataHolder` - is it a buffer with a size greater than zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LongHolder written = new LongHolder();

while (true) {
    exchangeStream64.Read(data, READ_AMOUNT, dataAmount);
    if (0 == dataAmount.value) {
        break;
    }

    jos.write(data.value, (int)dataAmount.value, (int)written.value);
}
```

It may be just a copy&paste mistake here, but the last parameter of jos.write is always 0. That is the amount of bytes to write from the array.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really stupid copy&paste mistake. I've broken my head debugging all these streams :)